# LSB error messages when running an upgrade

Tags: 11.04, upgrade, wubi

After running sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade, I am shown this message in the terminal:

Package configuration

```
Configuring sysv-rc 
Unable to migrate to dependency-based boot system                           
Tests have determined that problems in the boot system exist which          
prevent migration to dependency-based boot sequencing:                      
insserv: warning: script 'K20acpi-support' missing LSB tags and             
overrides, insserv: warning: script 'alsa-store' missing LSB tags and       
overrides, insserv: warning: script 'irqbalance' missing LSB tags and       
overrides, insserv: warning: script 'dbus' missing LSB tags and             
overrides, insserv: warning: script 'udevtrigger' missing LSB tags and      
overrides, insserv: warning: script 'gdm' missing LSB tags and              
overrides, insserv: warning: script 'console-setup' missing LSB tags and
```

---

```
Configuring sysv-rc
Unable to migrate to dependency-based boot system                           
Tests have determined that problems in the boot system exist which          
prevent migration to dependency-based boot sequencing:                      
insserv: warning: script 'K20acpi-support' missing LSB tags and             
overrides, insserv: warning: script 'alsa-store' missing LSB tags and       
overrides, insserv: warning: script 'irqbalance' missing LSB tags and       
overrides, insserv: warning: script 'dbus' missing LSB tags and             
overrides, insserv: warning: script 'udevtrigger' missing LSB tags and      
overrides, insserv: warning: script 'gdm' missing LSB tags and              
overrides, insserv: warning: script 'console-setup' missing LSB tags and    
ok
```

I am not sure how to fix that. Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove --purge all those packages and try again the `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

That will do the trick.